# Why is PHP not retrieving data sent by AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

So I'm trying to make a contact form with a button, not submit button, that runs a function when clicked `onClick = 'send()'` and on localhost w/ WAMP it works perfectly sending the email with its contents. On a live version, the connection is well and I receive the email but I don't get the respective form field data even though it's the same code I used when testing on WAMP server. Also, in the top of the php file I echoed the POST data and on localhost it would say the information but on live, again, it doesn't.

- I have also tried `.val()` instead of `.serialize()` as shown below but no luck.
- I have also done `data: {name:name, email:email...}` as well as `data{'name':name, 'email':email...}`

Any help would be appreciated!

Heres the AJAX:

```
function send(){

    var name = $("input[name=name]").serialize();
    var email = $("input[name=email]").serialize();
    var textarea = $("textarea").serialize();
    var business = $("input[name=business]").serialize();
    var website = $("input[name=website]").serialize();

    alert(name);
    alert(email);
    alert(textarea);
    alert(business);
    alert(website);

        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'sendmail.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {name, email, textarea, business, website},
            success: function(mydata) {
                alert(mydata);
            }
        });

    }
```

and heres the PHP:

```
<?php

        echo($_POST['name']);
        // does show as output on localhost w/wamp but on live website its mute

        $message=
        'Full Name: '.$_POST['name'].'<br />
        Email:  '.$_POST['email'].'<br />
        Message: '.$_POST['textarea'].'<br />
        Current Website: '.$_POST['website'].'<br />
        Business Name: '.$_POST['business'].'<br />
        ';

        /* Email Sending Script */

        if (!$mail->send()) {
            echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            die("true");    
        }

?>
```

NETWORK TABS

Request Headers:
http://prntscr.com/ck0btg

Post Data:
http://prntscr.com/ck0cni

Comment: did you check the network and that it have any errors?

Comment: Right under the success function, add an `error:` function, identical to `success:`. Does that output anything?

Comment: If your JS is not running on the same server, you need to add `http://localhost/xx.php`

Comment: @James111 On localhost it works fine, its the live version on my website where it stops working

Comment: @Howzieky No, it sends the email with no errors but with blank fields.

Comment: In the Ajax request, place the URL to your php file!

Comment: @JohnDoe what does it say when you replace `data: {name, email, textarea, business, website},` with (no quotes around the keys) `data: {name: name, email: email, textarea: textarea, business: business, website: website},`? By the way, the first one is invalid. Keep it to the second one

Comment: check the network maybe it does have an error
https://gyazo.com/c1e6f80da968c9276c66a5415587f10a

Comment: Also, be certain you have jQuery included in your site.

Comment: @Howzieky he said it works in localhost so it means he already include it.

Comment: @Howzieky Yeah I definitely have jQuery and I've tried the replacement you suggested before with the same results.

Comment: @JohnDoe did you check your network does it have any error?

Comment: @NewbeeDev nothing at all with the network

Comment: try adding var_dump($_POST); exit; first line of your php code

Comment: @NewbeeDev That would still work on localhost but on live website the echo is "array(0){}." This is giving me a strong feeling that the data isn't being sent at all through AJAX.

Comment: try viewing your network headers kindly check your form data if those data are in the list https://gyazo.com/c3d2836d92ae6a255e3d7bbd19a8ae3a to know if your data are successfully passed in your ajax request

Comment: Is there any errors in the console?

Comment: Make sure the url is correct and that it is actually going to that file.  To be sure put the full path to the file

Comment: When people are saying *"check your network"*, they mean the *Network* console in your browser. You should be able to see the POST request to `sendmail.php` along with the data sent

Comment: @Howzieky OP appears to be using ES6 object literal shorthand which is supported by modern browsers so `{name, email, textarea, business, website}` is actually valid

Comment: If nothing else works try replacing the `$_POST` with `$_REQUEST` in your PHP script and then call that script manually with an argument string. You can prepare that string with jquery's `$.param()` function. See how the system responds then.

Comment: Could there be a "compatibility mode" issue like in the case of IE11? You can set different behaviour of this browser for intranet and certain (named) domains.

Comment: @Phil Yea it says that the data is being sent via AJAX to that file but at the PHP file it doesn't "recognize" it at all.

Comment: @NewbeeDev Yea I see the same thing the data is being sent but not accessed, i guess, by the PHP script

Comment: @JohnDoe can you take a screenshot of the *Network* entry complete with the *"Request Headers"* and *"Form Data"* section and add it to your question?

Comment: @Phil Question updated, the screenshots are linked

Comment: @Phil THanks Phil for helping me but along the way of investigating the console I decided to delete the .htaccess file from a previous website and it worked!

Comment: still haven't solve it yet?

Comment: your Form Data look strange because it should have _method: Post but I haven't seen it https://gyazo.com/02707c60101a6cec2be24c69d2eb2778

Comment: @NewbeeDev yeah i solved it! thanks for your help. Answer is below

Comment: @JohnDoe what did you do?

Comment: @NewbeeDev I deleted the .he access file that stored data for 2 months upon page visit. Tampered with this data is guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the .htaccess file from the previous website I had is what caused the problem. Once I deleted it, it worked. I think its because I made it so all the content of the site was to be kept for 1 month (script from .htaccess) and that's what caused it not to send.

Answer (score 1):

use .serialize() method if you want to post all fields of Form alternatively In your code you have to pass data with key index, so you can get value of data using that key in your server side script

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "sendmail.php",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: $("Selector_of_Form").serialize(),
    success: function(mydata){
        alert(mydata);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding your data as JSON before you send it.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "sendmail.php",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: $.toJSON(postData),
    success: function(mydata){
        alert(mydata);
    }
});
```

Alternately, `JSON.stringify(postData)`

Comment: In place of postData I would enter name, email, etc.. correct?

Comment: 1) To send a JSON payload, the request headers should contain `Content-type: application/json`. 2) OP would need to change their PHP code to read the JSON payload from `php://input`. This is not compatible with OP's code that expects `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "sendmail.php",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: {"name":name, "email":email, "textarea":textarea, "business":business, "website":business},
    success: function(mydata){
        alert(mydata);
    }
});
```

Comment: I assume OP's browser supports ES6 object literal shorthand so this is no different

Comment: As @Phil says and also I've tried that before, no luck.